# Why oauth2 uses the same endpoint for different kind of authentication?

Tags: authentication, oauth, api-design

I'm reading the [oauth2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31) specs and it seems the `/token` endpoint must support all the authentication schemas (e.g basic authentication, code authentication (when the client receives a code from the oauth provider), refreshToken authentication etc ) which means that different params are required if a different schema is used but the same endpoint is used.

It happens that I'm developing an authentication module so my  question is:

**is this a good practice?**

Usually I assign different endpoints for each set of parameters required instead to create a routing mechanism based on the parameters I'm receiving. E.g. If the request requires an user and pass I would assign a new endpoint/route such  /auth/userPass, if it requires client and a code I would assign  /auth/oauth2Code  on token , auth/oauth2RefreshToken etc so that it can be easier to validate and debug.